# Understanding RouteProcessor.sol script and how to use the contract function

Tags: solidity, erc-20, contract-debugging, arbitrum, router

I am a beginner trying to understand what is the bot/contract transaction that is displayed in some DEXs. Attaching screenshot from dextools and pair link [here](https://www.dextools.io/app/en/arbitrum/pair-explorer/0x987fba18b4e883711a209c6b58da0c25877155b3).

[image]

I followed the transaction [here](https://arbiscan.io/tx/0xb5299ebf8ccdc82d1aa030c6d149ae79c42cc067d9eb6a4d09a3ebdae51f7bfe) and then to the following contract [here](https://arbiscan.io/address/0x9c6522117e2ed1fe5bdb72bb0ed5e3f2bde7dbe0#code). I saw that the contract function executed was the RouteProcessor and I tried to interact with the contract without any luck. Can someone explain or help me understand what I am doing wrong?

[image]

TIA